# How to detect the completion of gif using Glide?

Tags: android, gif, android-glide

I am trying to figure out how I can detect the last index of frame and when it is the last frame, which is the end frame. Then, I'd like to implement that it goes to the next activity.

It's SplashActivity.

But the problem is, I just get `-1` index all the time and it doesn't increase at all.

Here's my Glide code:

```
Glide.with(this)
        .asGif()
        .load(R.drawable.bg_splash)
        .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)) // Saves no data to cache.
        .listener(object : RequestListener<GifDrawable> {
            override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<GifDrawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.

                return false
            }

            override fun onResourceReady(resource: GifDrawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<GifDrawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                resource!!.setLoopCount(1)
                resource!!.start()
                while (true) {
                    Timber.d("resource: ${resource.frameIndex} / ${resource.frameCount}")
                    if (!resource!!.isRunning) {
                        break
                    } else {
                        if (resource.frameIndex == resource.frameCount - 1) {
                            val intent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, MainActivity::class.java)  // Intent 선언
                            startActivity(intent)
                            finish()
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out)
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false
            }

        })
        .into(iv_splash)
```

the result in logcat is:

```
resource: -1 / 216
resource: -1 / 216
resource: -1 / 216
resource: -1 / 216
...
```

How can I solve this problem!?

Comment: you probably need to check current frame in a separate thread. Doing it in same thread will block the gif from starting itself

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, one thead(Main Thread) is stuck in the while loop.

So, it needs one more thread for checking the current index. And let the UI thread(Main Thread) play.

My solution is:

```
Glide.with(this)
        .asGif()
        .load(R.drawable.bg_splash)
        .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)) // Saves no data to cache.
        .listener(object : RequestListener<GifDrawable> {
            override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<GifDrawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onResourceReady(resource: GifDrawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<GifDrawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                resource!!.setLoopCount(1)
                gifFrameCheckThread = Thread(Runnable {
                    while (true) {
                        Timber.d("resource: ${resource.frameIndex} / ${resource.frameCount}")
                        if (resource.frameIndex + 1 == resource.frameCount - 1) {
                            val intent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, MainActivity::class.java)  // Intent 선언
                            startActivity(intent)
                            gifFrameCheckThread.join()
                            finish()
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out)
                        }
                    }
                })
                gifFrameCheckThread.start()
                return false
            }
        })
        .into(iv_splash)
```